# Website not working on IE8, clueless

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I made a new website but when I check it out on IE8 (internet explorer 8) it shows a blank page. I tried finding a solution now for hours but can't seem to figure out what's wrong. Anyone here can help me out?

I have used jquery, css and html

Thanks alot!

http://www.badboot.be

Comment: Please post some code here. If your page goes dead, this question will no longer be useful to later visitors.

Comment: You have got JS errors, supersized could be the culprit.

Comment: your site is using HTML5 and CSS3?..if i m not wrong

Comment: All three children of `body` have `display: none` and the javascript console shows some errors. Check these. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The javascript console shows exceptions that go through the Supersized library initialisation routine and jQuery. *This indicates that the Supersized library is incompatible with IE8*.

This causes the code that unhides the page (I assume there is) not to run, and the children of `body` keep their `display: none`, which causes them to not appear.

Comment: Thank you this seems assumable to me ... I'm looking into it but for the moment I can't seem to find the solution. I will go true the script another time :)

All extra js is inline in the html

Comment: I'm so sorry, was not my intention ... I guess that happened as accident when I saw this post on my iphone. But I can't vote up because this ismy second time on stackoverflow and my reputation requires 15. Sorry again

Comment: @fabrikgrafik Can you remove the downvote please?